# Do computer languages instantiate only predicate calculus?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, symbolic-logic, philosophy-of-computer-science

All the computer languages I'm familiar with, be they imperative or declarative have the same core mechanics (arithmetic and logic).They have the same loops, conditionals etc. Whatever the language it seems to have the same logical power as the others despite the differences in syntax and attractiveness. A bash script can, with effort, be written to do the same thing a Prolog program.

**Question: can the commonly used computer languages be said to instantiate predicate logic only?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "instantiate"? A syntactical correct expression/statement in a programming language usually isn't said to be true.

Comment: They all "do the same thing" because all computers are, basically, glorified universal Turing machines, with the same types of programming instructions (loops, conditionals, memory recalls, etc.). This has nothing to do with the predicate calculus in particular, and can "instantiate" any formal "logic" whatsoever, or rather any computation whatsoever (since computation is not deduction we are not really dealing with logic). In essence, this is what the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) says.

Comment: There is a precise relation between programs and proofs, and programming languages and proof systems, known as the [Curry–Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence). For example, (intuitionistic) natural deduction systems "*can be directly interpreted... as a typed variant of the model of computation known as lambda calculus*". But the correspondence is not tied to any particular proof system (like predicate calculus) or to any particular model of computation.

Comment: Prolog deals directly with a limited form of first order logic known as horn clauses. The rule is the leftmost term must be non-negative.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have noted, this is a rather unclear question. However, there's an important sense in which the answer is **yes**.

*I'll write "N" for the set of natural numbers and **N** for the structure of the natural numbers with zero, successor, addition, and multiplication.*

Specifically, looking at a function F from N to N for simplicity, the following are equivalent:

- F is computable by a Turing machine (or equivalently, per the comments above, any Turing-complete programming language - which is all of the ones you'd actually use).
- F is *representable* in first-order Peano arithmetic PA (or indeed even less): there is a formula p(x,y) such that for each natural number n, there is exactly one natural number m such that PA proves p(n,m), and moreover that natural number is exactly f(n). *Here for simplicity I'm conflating a number with the corresponding numeral - e.g. 2 versus S(S(0)).*
- F is [Sigma^0_1-definable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) in **N**.

(Similar results hold for higher-arity functions, partial functions, and relations.)

So we have both provability and definability criteria, tied to first-order theories and structures respectively, which exactly capture computability. And indeed this is only a tiny fragment of first-order logic: there are non-computable sets of natural numbers (e.g. the Halting Problem) which are nonetheless first-order definable in **N**. Really, I would say that models of computation correspond to a *very tiny fragment* of first-order logic *specifically in the context of **N** or similar structures*.

---

That said, this isn't really the whole picture. Logics stronger than first-order logic are still "computable on finite structures" - e.g. we can brute-force determine whether a second-order sentence with *k* second-order quantifiers holds in a structure of size *n* in time more-or-less 2^(*kn*) - and this plays an important role in [descriptive complexity theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_complexity_theory) - the point being that we can often view *individual inputs* to algorithms as finite structures. By contrast, the above section is looking at how the *whole "input space"* is construed.

Comment: I think this would be a (qualified) yes to "instantiate a fragment of formal systems" rather than of predicate calculus. There are plenty of alternatives to the predicate calculus and Peano arithmetic, diagrammatic systems, for example, that have the same representational strength. Some look very differently, just as artificial neuronets look very differently from Turing machines, while having the same computational strength. The Curry-Howard isomorphism suggests a more immediate "instantiation" of the intuitionistic calculus.

Comment: @Conifold That's definitely a fair interpretation - the question isn't very specific on this point!

Answer (score 0):

> Do computer languages instantiate only predicate calculus?

I'm going to disagree with other respondents. The answer is a clear cut no. The why goes like this.

A computer in the lay sense is generally understood to be a general-purpose computational system built of physical stuff to accomplish three tasks: deciding among conditions, iterating through instructions, and branching based on conditionals. Roughly speaking, computers can evaluate truth and handle branches of the flow of computation. One popular formalism to describe this is the [Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine). Another is the [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). They have been shown to be formally equivalent which bring in the idea of the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis).

So, when you ask do computers instantiate only the predicate calculus, you are asking after what is the relationship between the lambda calculus and the [predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), which I'll simply refer to as first-order logic (FOL) in my response.

**So, what is the relationship between the lambda calculus and FOL? Are they same?**

No.

According to WP:

> Lambda calculus consists of constructing lambda terms and performing reduction operations on them. In the simplest form of lambda calculus, terms are built using only the following rules:
>
> - x : A variable is a character or string representing a parameter.
> - (λx.M) : A lambda abstraction is a function definition, taking as input the bound variable x (between the λ and the punctum/dot .) and returning the body M.
> - (MN) : An application, applying a function M to an argument N. Both M and N are lambda terms.

**What you see here can largely be conceived of as string manipulation, and this is the important part, *free of any context*.** In fact, the lambda calculus in the guise of Turing machine is a type of [automaton in the study of formal languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory). The lambda calculus is the language of [formal systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system).

[FOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) is a type of formal system that can be expressed in the lambda calculus. It is technically a [hyponym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy) because it adds requirements above and beyond the definitional criteria of the grammar of a lambda calculus. For instance, FOL requires the use of [truth-conditional semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-conditional_semantics). So, in FOL, you will see 'T' and 'F' which is not a requirement of the lambda calculus. Logical syntax is also introduced with [connectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) like '&','|', and '!' (in PL dialects, such symbols vary of course), and [universal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) and [existential quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) with symbols '∀' and '∃', resp. This translates to [variables, constants, declaration, and binding in compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). None of those grammatical requirements are required for a general notion of computation, but are conscious choices on how to design a programming language to actually do the computation what you want. Thus general purpose computers are built to execute a variety of logics (although their microprogrammatic primtives are themselves not flexible summoning up Boolean notions of logic).

Why do languages seem to do the same thing? Well, first, many languages are derivative of other languages. Consider the [Algol-family of languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL). Not only is it a closely related group of languages, but it was the ancestor of C, and C of course forked into C++ and Java to name a few. Secondly, programming languages attempt to take full advantage of a computers hardware or generalized abstraction. In other words, they strive to be Turing complete. Not all languages do; a [domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) for instance can be radically simpler if need be than a GPL.

So, while you see some similarities between programming languages that can be construed as implementing FOL, in effect, any variety of logics can be implemented in a programming language including [non-classical logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-classical_logic). A relatable example is a computer that implements a [fuzzy logic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) or a compiler, like NodeJS, that implements ES6 which has truth categories other than true and false. And remember, the distinction is because a software language is a flexible means of executing the arithmetic and logic that inheres in the ALU/CU.